# c# How to form list in below format

Tags: c#

In c# , I have an object as below

```
{"allAnimal":[{"AnimalType":"cat","AnimalCount":2}]}
```

now, i want in below format,

```
{"allAnimal":{"Animal" :[{"AnimalType":"cat","AnimalCount":2}]}}
```

My Code :

```
namespace ArrayOrList
{
    public class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AnimalSet list = new AnimalSet();

            Animal myAnimal = new Animal();

            myAnimal.AnimalType = "cat";
            myAnimal.AnimalCount = 2;
            list.allAnimal = new List<Animal>();

            myAnimal = new Animal();
            myAnimal.AnimalType = "dog";
            myAnimal.AnimalCount = 3;
            list.allAnimal.Add(myAnimal);

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list); 

        }
    }
    public class Animal
    {
        public string AnimalType { get; set; }
        public int AnimalCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnimalSet
    {
        public List<Animal> allAnimal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take you desired out put and either use [JSonToCSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or copy past special json to class in visual studio.

Comment: But double check your expected output first because it make no sense: Animal is a `List<Animal>`. `Animal` is a type. And `allAnimal` only has one property a list on Animal. No matter where you start to read the hierachy it looks like nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions -

```
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                RootAnimal list = new RootAnimal();
                list.allAnimal = new AllAnimal();
                Animal myAnimal = new Animal();
                list.allAnimal.Animal = new List<Animal>();

                myAnimal = new Animal();
                myAnimal.AnimalType = "dog";
                myAnimal.AnimalCount = 3;
                list.allAnimal.Animal.Add(myAnimal);
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            }

   public class Animal
    {
        public string AnimalType { get; set; }
        public int AnimalCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class AllAnimal
    {
        public List<Animal> Animal { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootAnimal
    {
        public AllAnimal allAnimal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Is there any other simple way to achieve the same, because my application has lot of objects like this in one single object.